# UsbManager returns null when getAccessoryList is called

Tags: android

I'm developing an app in which android-powered device acts as USB-Device(not USB-Host). So I need to find the host that my android device is connected to. Here is my code:

```
btnRefresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //UsbAccessory[] usbAccessory = new UsbAccessory[1];
                mUsbManager = (UsbManager)getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
                usbAccessory = mUsbManager.getAccessoryList();
                List<String> accessoryListTemp= new ArrayList<String>();

                if (usbAccessory != null) {
                    if (usbAccessory.length > 0) {
                        String hhhh = usbAccessory[0].getModel();
                        accessoryListTemp.add(hhhh);
                    }
                }
                //accessoryListTemp.add("hamed test item");
                ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapterTemp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                       android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, accessoryListTemp);
                arrayAdapterTemp.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

                spinnerHosts.setAdapter(arrayAdapterTemp);
            }
        });
```

I cannot figure out why I got null in accessoryListTemp variable. It probably means that there is no device found, but actually my device is connected and the other device finds it.
To be specific I'm connecting two android phone via USB and one of them is host and the other is device, but the device doesn't recognize host.

Comment: Maybe your device is in USB accessory mode and the other one acts like a host. Maybe because of that one of them can't retrieve accessory list?

Comment: actually that's true, one of them is in accessory mode and the other in host mode, but why I can't connect them in this way??

Comment: As I understand only the USB Host can retrieve accessory list.

Comment: In the developer.android.com tutorial is said that when you want to find hosts use getAccessoryList. may be accessory in this scope means hosts

Comment: Ok, you have two devices connected between each other - and only one can be the Host, so have you tried to getAccessoryList() on both of them? Or I'm getting you wrong?

Comment: the other is ok, in the host side I used getDevice and it works properly, but the problem is in the slave side.

Comment: I have a solution and I have a code where you will get getAccessoryList() list

Answer (score 0):

warning: you should use correct OTG line!!
check  android.hardware.usb.accessory in  uses-feature

```
<manifest ...>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.accessory" />

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="<version>" />
...
<application>
  <uses-library android:name="com.android.future.usb.accessory" />
    <activity ...>
        ...
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED"
            android:resource="@xml/accessory_filter" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: what do you mean exactly? OTG cable?

Comment: yes, my poor english. when u connect 2 mobile, is the slave mobile on charging？

Comment: Yes its charging but the slave one can't recognize the host and at the same time master mobile finds the slave one.

Comment: I have a solution if you need my help then drop a mail on  zafarhussain910@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

[image]I am adding snaps that will help you to check getAccessoryList and details